# android generate bitmap from google map without mapView

Tags: android, bitmap, maps, android-mapview

I want to generate a bitmap file using google maps without passing data through a mapView, like a background thread (downloading tiles in order to write the bitmap)

Does anyone has an idea?

an example is: entering coordinates and after clicking a button, the .png is generated in the SD Card, containing the COMPLETE loaded tiles.

any proposals?

thanks!!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This method returns url with map image

```
public static String getMapUrl(Double lat, Double lon, int width, int height) {
    final String coordPair = lat + "," + lon;
    return "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?"
            + "&zoom=16"
            + "&size=" + width + "x" + height
            + "&maptype=roadmap&sensor=true"
            + "&center=" + coordPair
            + "&markers=color:black|" + coordPair;
}
```

You can download or display it on ImageView

Comment: that is a good way, I will try it. I wanted to create no ImageView but a bitmap file and if its possible paint some information on the map/bitmap

Comment: Displaying on an `ImageView` is an option. If the method returns the url of the image, then of course you can save it in a `Bitmap`.

Comment: it definitly gives me an URL of the image, that can be downloaded.  Any idea how can I paint items or text to specific coordinates on this map/bitmap?

Comment: the items issue is well documented on [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/?hl=en#Markers) thank You

Answer (score 0):

When I paste the url generated from this code
in browser it gave me:
The Google Maps Platform server rejected your request. You must use an API key to authenticate each request to Google Maps Platform APIs. For additional information, please refer to http://g.co/dev/maps-no-account