# Is it possible to save Google Maps MapView as image?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm creating application that track user position by creating overlay on MapView (Google Maps Android API v2). is it possible to save map and its overlay as image?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12107608

Answer (score 3):

Use [google static maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/)   api. it returns the locations image with any overlay you (with scale,zoom,width,height,lat,long parameters)wish.And works with simple http request.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe it's possible in Google Maps Andoird API V2 yet.  See the question I asked a while back: [Capture screen shot of GoogleMap Android API V2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13773658/capture-screen-shot-of-googlemap-android-api-v2)

You can of course save a screenshot using DDMS, but I doubt that's what you're looking to do.

Comment: You can upvote/star the following feature request for Google to add screenshot support in the API: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4898

Answer (score 0):

this guy in the android development message threads had a similar problem:
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/eGOyIkj4BfU

He had the same issue you are having and seemed to have resolved it.

in iOS the problem is easy to fix. you can Render from context and save it as PNG or JPG in your camera roll or User Directory ;) Good luck with droid.